# How do I have a link that on click animates and shows a div?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

So I have a bar that I want to have a `sign up link` that when you click it, shows some text links to the left of the link.

There are some before and after visuals below.

I tried some javascript but didn't get far, I want it to animate out but its ok for now if I can't figure it out.  Any idea?

[image]
[image]

Comment: @paiCode It might be because the OP does not want to include a library in their document. Another reason might be because they do not know jQuery, or do not want to learn it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does this involve php? php is server side as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the **:target pseudo class selector** and some CSS3 transitions? In this case, when you click the link the opacity of the div changes and makes it visible. I'm not sure what browsers you need to support? This won't work in IE 7 or 8.

Here's the code for the transition:

HTML

```
<a href="#id1">Sign Up</a>
```

CSS

```
#id1 {

    opacity: 0;    
}


#id1:target {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
                                      opacity: 1;
```

Demo - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CYxd/)

Edit: Here's a second example (slide effect) that I quickly made, so it's not running smooth, but it shows at least what's possible - [jsFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/fj7gB/4/) (webkit).

Answer (score 0):

you can try using with jquery

```
$(function() {
$('#id').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#id2").animate({height : '410'}; /* what ever the styles u need */


});

})
```

try this links

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_effects.asp

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/understanding-jquery-animate-function/

Comment: A javascript solution has been asked for, you've provided jQuery

Comment: jQuery is a framework built with JavaScript to help JavaScript programmers who are doing common web tasks.

Comment: @paiCode: jQuery is a JavaScript library, not a language. There is no trivial way of accomplishing what the OP wants.

Comment: Why give the OP jQuery if he's not asking for it?

Comment: How do I insert the above code into a link? I need to put that in something like: <script type="text/javascript"> </script> tag but how do I have my link communicate with that code?

Comment: @paiCode: Using jQuery it is very easy to do such tasks ,so we should promote,or he should mention like only looking for javascript solution

Comment: I would second the use of something like jquery as leaves less room for bugs and why re-invent the wheel in this case.. Also make sure to use .stop before the animation

Comment: @paiCode : I mentioned only an example ,

Comment: I'm not against jQuery, I'm a jQuery developer myself, but have been downvoted in the past for answers like these.

@prash can you link a fiddle example to this? will make it easier for the OP

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('#id').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#id2").animate({height : '410'}; /* what ever the styles u need */
 });
});
```

Dont know why you want to put it in another function. That will do.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this using jQuery.

1. Give an id to your `sign up link` that you want to click.
2. Create a div, which has some height below your link and give it all the styling, in the way that you want to make it look when user click the link.
3. Give that div a css styling `height: 0px` so that the div will disappear now.
4. Use jQuery `.animate()` function to toggle (or change) the height of that div when a user click the link.

You can refer jQuery `.animate()` documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/.